# Opening the javascript action only when clicking a specific section of the div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on an albums page , and i have [this](https://codepen.io/sachinchoolur/pen/qNyvGW) script that will open the image in a bigger window so i can see it better, zoom , download, etc.

I modified it a little , and i am generating the pictures in a `foreach` from my database.

```
         <div id="lightgallery" class="row" >

             <?php $x=1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->upload as $upload): ?>
            <?php $dir = Users::currentUser()->id; ?>

                          <div class="col-sm-3"  data-src="<?= PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $upload->name ;?>" data-sub-html="<h4><?=$upload->name ?></h4>">

                                <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                                  <img src="<?= PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $upload->name ;?>" alt="Thumb-<?=$x?>" class="imgu">

                                </div>

                                <div class="caption text-center">
                                  <hr>
                             <p><?= $upload->name;?> </p>
                                   <div class="text-center">
                                     <a href="<?=PROOT?>upload/delete/<?=$upload->id?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs " onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure ?')){return false;} target='_blank' ">
                                       Delete
                                     </a>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     <?php $x++; ?>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </div>
```

The only problem i have with it so far is that i want the picture to be opened only when i click on the picture , but it opens the picture, no matter where i click on the div. Even if i click on the button `Delete` it will open the picture in a bigger window as the script does.

And the javascripts required as they are hidden on codepin.io

```
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/master/dist/js/lightgallery.js"></script>
                     <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-autoplay.js/master/dist/lg-autoplay.js"></script>
                     <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-fullscreen.js/master/dist/lg-fullscreen.js"></script>
                     <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/sachinchoolur/lg-zoom.js/master/dist/lg-zoom.js"></script>
                     <script> lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery')); </script>
```

Comment: where is the code for opening a bigger window??

Comment: @suhailc it's a javascript that will open it `<script> lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery')); </script>
`

Comment: add the full script in question

Comment: remove `id="lightgallery"` from the main div and add it to `<div class="thumbnail text-center">`

Comment: Go read the documentation for that script you are using there! These scripts are usually triggered by classes and/or attributes in the DOM. (The `data-src` and `data-sub-html` look like they might be involved here, so in that case, you would probably have to put them on an element closer to the image, like the link around it …)

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou I've already tried it , but it doesn't work.

Comment: @suhailc i've added them

Comment: @04FS that's why I am asking for help

Comment: Yeah my bad can't have the same id on multiple divs. Change it to a class and change your scipt to use `document.getElementsByClassName("lightgallery");` but you said you have made changes to the srciprt so it would be better to show us the full code so we don't have to make guesses

Comment: _“that's why I am asking for help”_ - and that’s why there’s _documentation_, so that ideally you would not even have to ;-) So, did you or did you not go check that out first of all? If so, how exactly did it not help?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou i've done changes only to html code

Comment: @04FS i did but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Then show us what exactly you tried, and explain your reasoning. The codepen you referred to basically already does what you want - so you don’t even need to do that much different, you just need to place these attributes on an element closer to the image, and not multiple levels up on an ancestor that contains other elements as well …

Comment: If you move these attributes from the `<div class="col-sm-3">` div one level lower, and place them on `<div class="thumbnail text-center">` … you should basically be done already. The JS part should be left alone, because it looks like the initialization only needs the reference to a parent container that contains all those elements.

Comment: @04FS if you would try to put some text in before the `<li>` closing tag , like '<h2>Clicking on text should not work</h2>' it will still open , i want it not to open when i click on the text. Maybe my question weren't accurate enough , and i apologize if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selector option while creating light gallery to set the selector for opening the gallery,

```
<div class="col-sm-3">

        <div class="thumbnail text-center">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="Thumb" class="imgu" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/300" data-sub-html="<h4>name </h4>">

        </div>

        <div class="caption text-center">
          <hr>
          <div>
            test div
          </div>
          <div class="text-center">
            <a href="<?=PROOT?>upload/delete/<?=$upload->id?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs " onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure ?')){return false;} target='_blank' ">
                                           Delete
                                         </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>



<script>
     lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'), {
      selector: ".imgu"
     });
</script>
```

in the above code, I used the image with class 'imgu' as the selector for gallery hence it will only open when the image is clicked, also provide the data-src and data-sub-html for the img tag
check the below fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/suhailsulu/Lya1hdtm/

Comment: Your method seems to work , but i am not getting the left/right buttons anymore. Any ideas ?

Comment: if you have more than one image it will work check my updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/suhailsulu/Lya1hdtm/